# ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y (NetworkX)

Tags: python, networkx

I want to plot the network for `gp.enrichment_map(gsea_res.res2d)`.

```
import gseapy as gp
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


nodes, edges = gp.enrichment_map(gsea_res.res2d)

# build graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,
                            source='src_idx',
                            target='targ_idx',
                            edge_attr=['jaccard_coef', 'overlap_coef', 'overlap_genes'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

# init node cooridnates
pos=nx.layout.spiral_layout(G)
#node_size = nx.get_node_attributes()
# draw node
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,
                       pos=pos,
                       cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
                       node_color=list(nodes.NES),
                       node_size=list(nodes.Hits_ratio *1000))
# draw node label
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,
                        pos=pos,
                        labels=nodes.Term.to_dict())
# draw edge
edge_weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'jaccard_coef').values()
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,
                       pos=pos,
                       width=list(map(lambda x: x*10, edge_weight)),
                       edge_color='#CDDBD4')
plt.show()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [307], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 pos=nx.layout.spiral_layout(G)
      5 #node_size = nx.get_node_attributes()
      6 # draw node
----> 7 nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,
      8                        pos=pos,
      9                        cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,
     10                        node_color=list(nodes.NES),
     11                        node_size=list(nodes.Hits_ratio *1000))
     12 # draw node label
     13 nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,
     14                         pos=pos,
     15                         labels=nodes.Term.to_dict())

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py:433, in draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist, node_size, node_color, node_shape, alpha, cmap, vmin, vmax, ax, linewidths, edgecolors, label, margins)
    430     node_color = apply_alpha(node_color, alpha, nodelist, cmap, vmin, vmax)
    431     alpha = None
--> 433 node_collection = ax.scatter(
    434     xy[:, 0],
    435     xy[:, 1],
    436     s=node_size,
    437     c=node_color,
    438     marker=node_shape,
    439     cmap=cmap,
    440     vmin=vmin,
    441     vmax=vmax,
    442     alpha=alpha,
    443     linewidths=linewidths,
    444     edgecolors=edgecolors,
    445     label=label,
    446 )
    447 ax.tick_params(
    448     axis="both",
    449     which="both",
   (...)
    453     labelleft=False,
    454 )
    456 if margins is not None:

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1412, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1409 @functools.wraps(func)
   1410 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1411     if data is None:
-> 1412         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1414     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1415     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1416                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:4378, in Axes.scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4374 s = np.ma.ravel(s)
   4375 if (len(s) not in (1, x.size) or
   4376         (not np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.floating) and
   4377          not np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.integer))):
-> 4378     raise ValueError(
   4379         "s must be a scalar, "
   4380         "or float array-like with the same size as x and y")
   4382 # get the original edgecolor the user passed before we normalize
   4383 orig_edgecolor = edgecolors

ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y
```

Data:

`gsea_res.res2d[1:5]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'Name': {1: 'gsea', 2: 'gsea', 3: 'gsea', 4: 'gsea'},
 'Term': {1: 'Canonical and non-canonical Notch signaling WP3845',
  2: 'miR-509-3p alteration of YAP1/ECM axis WP3967',
  3: 'Focal Adhesion WP306',
  4: 'Striated Muscle Contraction Pathway WP383'},
 'ES': {1: 0.6969705540478509,
  2: 0.81212075311302,
  3: 0.48417248403127733,
  4: 0.7654724255001505},
 'NES': {1: 2.1730818778829937,
  2: 2.1661621833197726,
  3: 2.1526281774632117,
  4: 2.14929157606087},
 'NOM p-val': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'FDR q-val': {1: 0.0017047353760445683,
  2: 0.0011364902506963788,
  3: 0.0014206128133704735,
  4: 0.0015910863509749303},
 'FWER p-val': {1: 0.003, 2: 0.003, 3: 0.004, 4: 0.006},
 'Tag %': {1: '7/23', 2: '8/17', 3: '61/153', 4: '8/21'},
 'Gene %': {1: '2.89%', 2: '7.74%', 3: '21.87%', 4: '1.76%'},
 'Lead_genes': {1: 'MFAP2;HEY1;DNER;NOTCH2;NOTCH3;JAG1;RRAS',
  2: 'COL3A1;FN1;COL1A1;PBX3;SPARC;COL5A1;TEAD1;EDNRA',
  3: 'MYL12A;COL1A2;FN1;CAV2;ACTG1;CAV1;MYL9;LAMA2;COL6A2;COL1A1;KDR;ITGAV;CAPN2;EGFR;RHOA;COL5A2;PDGFD;PTEN;CTNNB1;VCL;MAPK10;TLN2;HGF;PARVA;SPP1;TLN1;VEGFC;EGF;THBS3;ACTN1;FLNC;COL4A1;PAK1;COL4A2;FLNB;ILK;SOS1;PDGFC;BAD;HRAS;MET;LAMB2;PIK3R1;CDC42;SRC;RAP1B;BIRC2;PPP1R12A;ITGB4;PPP1CB;MYL12B;ITGB1;PIK3CD;VEGFB;COL5A3;JUN;PIK3R3;DIAPH1;CCND2;ACTB;ACTN4',
  4: 'ACTA2;TPM2;ACTG1;MYL9;TPM4;VIM;TPM1;TNNC1'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the nodes (node 0) in your dataframe is disconnected from all the other nodes. In consequence, when you load your network from the dataframe using `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` node 0 isn't loaded to your graph. This is easy to check by just running `G.nodes(data=True)` which returns `[(1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {})]`.
This mismatch between number of nodes in the dataframe and number of nodes in the graph triggers the error you're getting. To work around that, you can just load the missing node with: `G.add_node(nodes.index[0])`.

See full code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import gseapy as gp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data=pd.DataFrame({'Name': {1: 'gsea', 2: 'gsea', 3: 'gsea', 4: 'gsea'},
 'Term': {1: 'Canonical and non-canonical Notch signaling WP3845',
  2: 'miR-509-3p alteration of YAP1/ECM axis WP3967',
  3: 'Focal Adhesion WP306',
  4: 'Striated Muscle Contraction Pathway WP383'},
 'ES': {1: 0.6969705540478509,
  2: 0.81212075311302,
  3: 0.48417248403127733,
  4: 0.7654724255001505},
 'NES': {1: 2.1730818778829937,
  2: 2.1661621833197726,
  3: 2.1526281774632117,
  4: 2.14929157606087},
 'NOM p-val': {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'FDR q-val': {1: 0.0017047353760445683,
  2: 0.0011364902506963788,
  3: 0.0014206128133704735,
  4: 0.0015910863509749303},
 'FWER p-val': {1: 0.003, 2: 0.003, 3: 0.004, 4: 0.006},
 'Tag %': {1: '7/23', 2: '8/17', 3: '61/153', 4: '8/21'},
 'Gene %': {1: '2.89%', 2: '7.74%', 3: '21.87%', 4: '1.76%'},
 'Lead_genes': {1: 'MFAP2;HEY1;DNER;NOTCH2;NOTCH3;JAG1;RRAS',
  2: 'COL3A1;FN1;COL1A1;PBX3;SPARC;COL5A1;TEAD1;EDNRA',
  3: 'MYL12A;COL1A2;FN1;CAV2;ACTG1;CAV1;MYL9;LAMA2;COL6A2;COL1A1;KDR;ITGAV;CAPN2;EGFR;RHOA;COL5A2;PDGFD;PTEN;CTNNB1;VCL;MAPK10;TLN2;HGF;PARVA;SPP1;TLN1;VEGFC;EGF;THBS3;ACTN1;FLNC;COL4A1;PAK1;COL4A2;FLNB;ILK;SOS1;PDGFC;BAD;HRAS;MET;LAMB2;PIK3R1;CDC42;SRC;RAP1B;BIRC2;PPP1R12A;ITGB4;PPP1CB;MYL12B;ITGB1;PIK3CD;VEGFB;COL5A3;JUN;PIK3R3;DIAPH1;CCND2;ACTB;ACTN4',
  4: 'ACTA2;TPM2;ACTG1;MYL9;TPM4;VIM;TPM1;TNNC1'}})

nodes, edges = gp.enrichment_map(data)

# build graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges,source='src_idx',target='targ_idx',edge_attr=['jaccard_coef', 'overlap_coef', 'overlap_genes'])

G.add_node(nodes.index[0]) #add missing node
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
# init node cooridnates
pos=nx.layout.spiral_layout(G)

# draw node
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos=pos,cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu,node_color=list(nodes.NES),node_size=list(nodes.Hits_ratio *1000))

# draw node label
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos=pos,labels=nodes.Term.to_dict())

# draw edge
edge_weight = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'jaccard_coef').values()
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos=pos,width=list(map(lambda x: x*100, edge_weight)),edge_color='#CDDBD4')
plt.show()
```

[image]